# Smartcard: implicit DF selection

Tags: smartcard, apdu, smartcard-reader

I am studying about ISO7816-4 and I have a vague point in it.
My question is: What is implicit DF selection?
Please help me!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the card personalization, a DF different from the MF might be selected after reset. Implicit, because you don't have to send a SELECT command. This may be useful for single-purpose cards, where the main application resides in this implicitly selected DF.

Whether the card supports it, may be indicated in the *Card capabilities* in the historical bytes of the ATR, see ISO 7816-4.

In javacard context the corresponding mechanism is called *implicitly selected application*.

Comment: Thanks BRO, I have one more question: Can we set a certain DF to be a implicit selected DF or it's default DF of the card and could not be changed?

Comment: depends on the smart card implementation. there is no other way but to read the manufacturer's manual